# Can't detect the exact position of a sprite running an action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I need to do the following: a sprite is moved to a position, when the sprite goes to this position, I need to execute the reverse action.
For testing in this example I just print "ok" when I reach that position, avoiding so to over-release the action and to risk some exception.

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        soldier=[CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"soldier.gif"];
        soldier.position= CGPointMake(250, 250);
        [self addChild: soldier];
        CGPoint position=[soldier convertToNodeSpace: CGPointZero];
        CCMoveTo* move=[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration: 2 position: position];
        [move retain];
        [soldier addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"position" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: (void*)move];
        [soldier runAction: move];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    CGPoint position= [self convertToNodeSpace: soldier.position];
    if(CGPointEqualToPoint(position, CGPointZero));
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
}
```

The problem is that it prints "ok" a lot of times, it should print it only a time, why?

**EDIT**

I removed the extra ';' :

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    CGPoint position= [self convertToNodeSpace: soldier.position]; // breakpoint here
    if(CGPointEqualToPoint(position, CGPointZero))
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
}
```

Now it never prints "ok".In the breakpoint I print position and the last value is (47,47), it never reaches (0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use KVO/KVC with cocos2d for the simple reason that cocos2d is not KVC/KVO compliant. A Cocos2D class' properties might change without you ever getting a notification.

I don't know if this is the problem here or not, but there's a good chance if you continue with KVC/KVO you'll eventually run into problems.

Comment: What would you suggest then? I need to know the action stops.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon following the first line of your if statement inside your `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method. Because of it, the `NSLog` function is being called unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you.So now it doesn't print a lot of ok's, but it never prints ok.I edited the answer.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Since you're performing a conversion of the `CGPoint`, why don't you try placing a `NSLog` statement inside to visually determine if the converted point ever reaches `CGPointZero`?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Try *not* performing the conversion on the point inside `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`. Since you've repaired your conditional, it obviously never equates to true.

Comment: Even if I do so it never reaches CGZeroPoint.The sprite is moving towards CGZeroPoint, do you know how to detect the end of movement using observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change ?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I have no idea what is happening inside your `-runAction:` method, but everything else you've done looks fine. That your notification method was being called (and still is, though your conditional is evaluating to false) should prove that. Here's another suggestion: is 47 the height and width of your sprite, perchance?